# How to remove search button in AOSP Settings app

Tags: java, android-source

I am building AOSP for a custom device which is running only one app. The user of the device should be able to connect to wifi, but not to be able to make any other settings.
Unfortunately the settings app of Android 10 has this search button in the Actionbar  (see screenshot). From here the user could jump to any other menu in the settings.

I want to remove the search button but i cant find the place where it is inserted. It looks like that it is dynamically created by PreferenceScreen.

Anyone knows where to find it.

[image]

Comment: Have you got solution? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

Delete the searchbar from **packages/apps/Settings/res/layout/settings_homepage_container.xml**

```
<include layout="@layout/search_bar"/>
```